# @section's Content is Not Showing in @yield

Tags: laravel-8, yield, sections

I just learnt Laravel for a few days and have this problem.
The contents I write in welcome file is not showing.

layouts/main.blade.php

```
<div class="1">
@yield('trial')
</div>
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('trial')
<h2>test</h2>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view ('main');
    }
}
```

I've found some related questions and the solution in the forum, but still can't fix it.

Comment: You need to `return view ('welcome');` instead of `return view ('main');`

Comment: It's still not working. Tried change 'endsection' to 'stop', change my browser to Mozilla too, but still not working.

Comment: I don't see how that would not work. Maybe run `php artisan view:clear` to clear the view cache. What does the resulting source look like? Is `<div class="1"></div>` there? Maybe add some "debug" text before `@yield('trial')`, see if that gets output. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#layouts-using-template-inheritance